# Angular Components are not updating if i show in another component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have simple 2 components

med-create.html

```
<mat-card>
  <form (submit)="onAddPost(postForm)" #postForm="ngForm">
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <input matInput type="text" ngModel name="name" #name="ngModel" required placeholder="Medicine Name">
      <mat-error *ngIf="name.invalid">Please enter a medicine name </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <br>
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <input matInput type="text" ngModel name="company" #company="ngModel" required placeholder="Medicine company">
      <mat-error *ngIf="company.invalid">Please enter a medicine company </mat-error>

    </mat-form-field>
    <br>
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <input matInput type="text" ngModel name="type" #type="ngModel" required placeholder="Medicine type">
      <mat-error *ngIf="type.invalid">Please enter a medicine type </mat-error>

    </mat-form-field> <br>
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <input matInput type="text" ngModel name="quantity" #quantity="ngModel" required placeholder="Medicine quantity">
      <mat-error *ngIf="quantity.invalid">Please enter a medicine quantity </mat-error>

    </mat-form-field>
    <br>
    <button mat-raised-button type="submit" color="accent">Save</button>
  </form>
</mat-card>


<app-med-list [records]="storedRecord"></app-med-list>
```

med-create.ts

```
export class MedCreateComponent implements OnInit {
  enteredContent = '';
  enteredTitle = '';
  @Output() recordCreated = new EventEmitter<MED>();

  storedRecord: MED[] = [];

  onPostAdded(rec){
    this.storedRecord.push(rec);
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onAddPost(form: NgForm){
    if(form.invalid){
      return;
    }

     const rec: MED = {name: form.value.name, company: form.value.company, type: form.value.type, quantity: form.value.quantity}
     console.log(rec);
     this.recordCreated.emit(rec);
     form.resetForm();

  }
}
```

med-list.html

```
<table *ngIf="records.length > 0" id="users">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
  </tr>

  <tr *ngFor="let p of records">
    <td>{{p.name}}</td>
    <td>{{p.company}}</td>
    <td>{{p.type}}</td>
    <td>{{p.quantity}}</td>

  </tr>
</table>

<p *ngIf="records.length == 0" class="info-text mat-body-1">No Records added yet</p>
```

med-list.ts

```
export class MedListComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'company', 'type', 'quantity'];

  @Input() records: MED[] = [];

  constructor() { 
    
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.records);
  }

}
```

In med-create I have a simple form and showing my second component in html. I just need to pass data by @input and @output decorater. First I try to do same thing in app.component.html which is working absolutely fine but when I show my med-list component in my med-create component its not updating. All the time the

text which say no record found is showing. If I move this component to app.component.html its working fine. I need to know what I am doing wrong why its not working in component ?

Comment: Who is `recordCreated` emitting to? Is that even used?

Also, the method, `onPostAdded`, which adds to the `storedRecords` array is never called. Since this array is never modified and you are passing this array into `med-list`, you won't see any changes to the list.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not using Output event in any way. The main reason of using output event is for communication between **child => parent component** not from **parent component => child component**. So based on this in your scenario you have to modify your code something like the following.
**med-create.ts [Parent Component]**

```
export class MedCreateComponent implements OnInit {
  enteredContent = '';
  enteredTitle = '';
  @Output() recordCreated = new EventEmitter<MED>();

  storedRecord: MED[] = [];


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onAddPost(form: NgForm){
    if(form.invalid){
      return;
    }

     const rec: MED = {name: form.value.name, company: form.value.company, type: form.value.type, quantity: form.value.quantity}
     console.log(rec);
     this.storedRecord.push(rec); // Push record in your array here which is passed to child component via input attribute
     this.recordCreated.emit(rec);
     form.resetForm();

  }
}
```